# How to set settings to get recorded audio file size in kb?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on audio recording and uploading. While uploading 10secs audio I'm getting the 4GB data, I browsed and followed one of the answers in StackOverflow, changed settings as shown below and audio file format to .3gp, but data size not reduced.

```
-(void) startRecording{
[_recordButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSError *error;
// Recording settings
NSLog(@"%f", [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] sampleRate]);
NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[settings setValue:  [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
[settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12000.0] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];

NSArray *searchPaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *pathToSave = [documentPath_ stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AudioName.3gp"];
// File URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToSave];//FILEPATH];
//Save recording path to preferences
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setURL:url forKey:@"Test1"];
[prefs synchronize];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

// Create recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
recorder.delegate=self;
[recorder recordForDuration:10];
[self startTimerToMoveSlider];
}
```

Can anybody please guide me

Comment: Thank you, @Rakesh Patel, I modified and tested but still not reduced size.

Comment: You should have to set a Bit Rate as well as Quality.  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
AVEncoderBitRateKey : 12000,

Comment: I tried but not worked

Comment: can yuou show some piece of code to make clear why size is not getting reduce.??

Comment: Ok Sure, can i edit previous code and post there ?

Comment: yes...You can edit previous one

Comment: I edited, that is the method I used when record button is clicked

Comment: [settings setValue:  [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMin] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];...May be this factor helps you for desired output. Quality as i given that was max...please set to min

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried but still not solved, are the changes working for you, I'm not understanding why it is not reducing

Comment: If there doesn't change anything that means your setting not working..NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

Comment: Ok, I will investigate regarding these settings, Thank you, @Rakesh Patel.

Comment: "AudioName.3gp"--> Your file extension has create an issue. change it to "AudioName.aac"

Comment: @Rakesh Patel, Tried that also, but not solved, in my code something goes wrong, trying to solve.

Comment: @Rakesh, my mistake is that I'm calculating size by bytes of NSData of recorded audio while debugging, so it shows me wrong value. Issue solved now.

Comment: Thats great..Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved audio file size issue, here is my code for recording 30seconds audio and getting file size nearly 60kb-70kb.

```
-(void) startRecording{
[_recordButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSError *error;

NSString *pathToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.m4a", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];

// File URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToSave];//FILEPATH];

// Recording settings
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt:12000],AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                nil];
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url path] options: 0 error:&error];

//Save recording path to preferences
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setURL:url forKey:@"Test1"];
[prefs synchronize];

// Create recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
recorder.delegate=self;
[recorder prepareToRecord];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

[recorder recordForDuration:30];//recording for 30secs
[self startTimerToMoveSlider];//to move slider while recording
```

}

Note : #define DOCUMENTS_FOLDER [NSHomeDirectory()       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]